# How to erase all data from an array of structs that is not dynamically allocated

Tags: c, arrays, struct, null

In my program ( **C** Language ) I need to have a function that when called erases all the data of an array of structs. The array it is not dynamically allocated, so free will not work. Is there a way besides having to loop through everything and setting it to 0?

Comment: [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) ?

Comment: how about [memset](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/memset.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
memset(struct_variable_address, 0, sizeof(your_Struct));
```

Comment: I'd recommend: `memset(struct_variable_address, 0, sizeof(*struct_variable_address));` This is less error prone, in case the variables declaration changes.

Comment: this one is nicer than mine.

Answer (score 2):

In this case there will be always a loop. However you can use [`memset()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/memset/) if you don't want to add the loop yourself.

Answer (score 0):

erases all the data of an array of structs. the array it is not dynamically allocated, so in the case use ***memset()*** function is useful to  don't want to add the loop.